# Right Exactness of Inverse Image Functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules and $f: X \to Y$ a morphism of ringed spaces. 
I already know that the functor $_*:\mathcal{F} \to f_*(\mathcal{F})$ is left exact (and contrav) and $^{-1}:\mathcal{G} \to f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ is exact.

Let consider the functor $^*:\mathcal{G} \to f^*(\mathcal{G})$ (here $f^*(\mathcal{G}) := f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) \otimes _{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{O}_X$).
Futhermore I know that $f_*$ and $f^*$ are adjoint, therefore we have $Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(f^*(\mathcal{G}),\mathcal{F}) \cong Hom_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{G}, f_*(\mathcal{F}))$.

My question how we can follow from the ADJUNCTION and left exactness of $f_*$  that $f^*$ is  right exact?

Indeed, I know that one can easy conclude the right exactness of $f^*$ by using only exactness of $f^{-1}$ and right exactness of tensoring $- \otimes _{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{O}_X$ but I'm interested in a way using the given adjunction.

Comment: Left adjoints commute with colimits, e.g., they are right exact.

Comment: And how to see that functors commuting with colimits are right exact?

Comment: A cokernel is a specific kind of colimit.